# When paging the table with JS, the data from the Firebase database does not appear

Tags: javascript, pagination

I am extracting data from Firebase database using Javascript. I list them with table. I need to paging because this data is quite a lot. I did not apply the paging method in the following link to my script and this paging works.

**JS Pagination URL:**
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap

My problem is that the data comes from the database, so this script doesn't see my data and doesn't paging them and writes in index.html. **"No data available in table"**

This is because this paging function runs immediately when the script is first loaded.

> **Function:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#userlist-table').DataTable();
} );
```

It also works great when I put the data loaded from the database into the "table" as HTML.

```
<tbody><tr id="++-LstSrLoH2UdYFvYJRn9" role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">John Doe</td><td>A</td><td>Melbourne</td></tr><tr id="++-LstSrLoH2UdYFvYJRnA" role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">John Doe</td><td>A</td><td>Melbourne</td></tr><tr id="++-LstSrLoH2UdYFvYJRnB" role="row" class="odd"><td class="sorting_1">John Doe</td><td>A</td><td>Melbourne</td></tr><tr id="++-LstSrLoH2UdYFvYJRnC" role="row" class="even"><td class="sorting_1">John Doe</td><td>A</td><td>Melbourne</td></tr></tbody>
```

Somehow I have to run this function a little later and introduce the data in the table in the HTML to the paging function. I tried to use a timer, but I didn't get results and I wasn't able to generate an idea because I was new to JS. How can I solve this problem? I'm sorry about my bad English.

> **My HTML:**

```
<head>
    <!-- jquery latest version -->
    <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- table pagination css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
                        <table id="userlist-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="tr">
                                <th>Name</th> 
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Office</th>
                                </tr>  
                            </thead>
                        </table> 
</body>
```

> **My Script:**

```
var database = firebase.database().ref('MyDatabase');

database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){

        var content = '';

        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();

            content +='<tr id="' + "++" + data.key + '">';
            content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.position + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.office + '</td>';
            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#userlist-table').append(content);
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#userlist-table').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. I finally found the problem. This is because the ready paging script I used needs **" "**. I added a hollow **"tbody"** to the ready set and filled it with data from the Firebase database. Then, when the script was loaded, I ran the paging function with the **timer** and everything seems to be running smoothly. It can solve the problem if someone needs it.

> **My HTML:**

```
<head>
    <!-- jquery latest version -->
    <script src="assets/js/vendor/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    <!-- table pagination css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
                        <table id="userlist-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr id="tr">
                                <th>Name</th> 
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Office</th>
                                </tr>  
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>//add this element for pagination script
                        </table> 
</body>
```

> **My Script:**

```
var database = firebase.database().ref('MyDatabase');
window.setTimeout(getDatas, 2000);//add this line for timer with ur function for load datas

database.once('value', function(snapshot){
    if(snapshot.exists()){

        var content = '';

        snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            var val = data.val();

            content +='<tr id="' + "++" + data.key + '">';
            content += '<td>' + val.name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.position + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.office + '</td>';
            content += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#userlist-table').append(content);
    }
});

function getDatas(){
  $('#userlist-table').DataTable();
} //add this function, when loaded page, works it with timer
```